# rsync and --remove-source-files

Tags: rsync

I use rsync v. 3.0.4 and when I need to move something I use it with the --remove-source-files. I prefer rsync than mv.

Unfortunately, when I use --remove-source-files, the directories are left on the source side (as said in the man). Is there a way to remove directories too once moved all the files?

Comment: It might make sense to file a ticket with the rsync developers. An option to remove the directories as well would be a nice thing to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always delete them manually with something like this:

```
find /path/to/directory -depth -type d -print0 \
    | xargs --null --no-run-if-empty rmdir --
```

This will only delete empty directories.

Comment: A much more elegant solution with current find versions would be: `find /path/to/directory -type d -empty -delete`

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get `rsync` to write a log file in a format that your script could parse for the names of the directories to delete. See `man rsyncd.conf` for the available log format escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just "rm -rf" them?

Comment: yes of course, that's what I do. But in an automated process (a script) I would like it's the program doing that, otherwise I have to launch a script after that and I have to make checks on not-empty directories before deleting them. Not impossible to do but I'm looking for something ready to go.